# GIT error in Azure DEVOPS - SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain Pushing

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

When pushing a commit to Azure Devops I am getting this error.

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed
> with a fatal error. unable to access
> 'https://xx@dev.azure.com/xx/Lulo/_git/LuloBackend/': SSL certificate
> problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain Pushing to
> https://xx@dev.azure.com/x/Lulo/_git/LuloBackend

First I thought it was my company network or firewall, so I switched to mobile data, but the error is the same.

The 2nd thing is that I changed recently my password for my Azure AD Account, do I have to change something in Visual Studio in the GIT settings?

Comment: You can try to use `git config --global http.sslVerify false` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below command could help you achieve what you want? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT thanks, the above command shared by you helped me resolve this error "fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/SurajPardeshi/Git-Demo/_git/Git-Demo/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the error message, you can use `git config --global http.sslVerify false` to resolve the error.

Comment: Would this not compromise the security?

Comment: @resp78 it would most certainly not help the situation. Other answer should be prefered, worked for me just fine.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution, and opens up a security vulnerability.

Comment: disabling https verification is bad practice, so downvote

Answer (score 97):

In Visual Studio, go to `Git Settings` and Set `Cryptographic network provider` to **`Secure Channel`**

Comment: This worked for me in Visual Studio 2019 after I noticed Push stopped working.  Before I set the setting to "Secure Channel", the value was "Unset"

Comment: The VS docs to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-settings?view=vs-2019

Comment: worked like a charm.  I wonder why VS2019 just has this error out of the blue, my git pull has been working and suddenly it stops...but thanks for this step, it works again.

Comment: VS2019 started having this problem out of the blue for me too. This solution fixed it, and as Sandra mentioned, mine was also set to "Unset."

Comment: Same issue with VS 2022.  This fixed it.

Comment: Tools > Options. Source Control > Git Global Settings.

Comment: If using git SCM (CLI) on Windows, type `git config --global http.sslBackend schannel`

Comment: This worked for me today in VS2022.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue started in VS2022 after an upgrade. Following setting sorted the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Azure Git repository, click on "Clone". In the overlay screen, click on "Generate Git Credentials". This refreshes the credentials and solves the issue.[image]

Answer (score -2):

I solved the issue on my machine by using Tools & Features... removing "Git for Windows".. and readding it.

[image]